# PWC6188: The absolute uri ... cannot be resolved when launched from JAR

Tags: java, jsp, ant, jar, jetty

I am currently getting this error when trying to view a webpage hosted on an embedded Jetty server.

> HTTP ERROR 500
>   
> Problem accessing /. 
>   
> Reason:    /header.jsp(2,61) PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

**I can launch the start class from eclipse as a java application and everything works perfectly, its only once I launch it from the jar that was created using ANT that I receive this error.**

I've been reading posts here that talk about needing certain jars and things, but I assume all of that is already working since launching it inside eclipse works.

I have tried a few different tweaks of the jars to try to get it to work. 
I currently have the following jars in the web lib folder

- jetty-all-8.1.9.v20130131.jar
- jetty-runner-8.1.9.v20130131
- servlet-api.jar

I am executing the program using the following command

> java -jar webserver.jar

The webserver.jar runs the following code

```
    try
    {
        Server server = new Server();

        Connector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
        connector.setPort( 80 );
        server.addConnector( connector );

        WebAppContext wac = new WebAppContext();
        wac.setContextPath( "/" );
        wac.setExtractWAR( true );
        wac.setWar( "dist/WAR-Files/website.war" );

        server.setHandler( wac );

        server.setStopAtShutdown( true );
        logger.debug( "Attempting to start server..." );
        server.start();
        logger.debug( "Server state: " + server.getState() );
        server.join();
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        logger.error( e.getLocalizedMessage(), e );
    }
```

Here is the descriptor file I am using:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
metadata-complete="false" version="3.1">

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Can anyone help with this or suggest anything I could be doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to resolve this myself.

If anyone else comes across this issue, mainly that it works in eclipse but not as an exported jar... try to extract the included jars instead of packaging them. That's what fixed it for me.

Hopefully this will save someone else a lot of time!